# Standard plugins installed for hudson?

Tags: hudson

What are the standard plugins you all will install for hudson as a build server?

I know e.g. Findbugs.

If the hudson server don't have internet access how do i download the package from internet and steup in the intranet hudson server?

Thanks

Comment: Sonar - http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin without Internet access, you can download the *.hpi file on another system, put it in the `plugins` directory of your hudson install, and restart hudson.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins#Plugins-Byhand